# How to implement WTSRegisterSessionNotification function

Tags: c++, windows, events, wtsapi32

I want to implement `WTSRegisterSessionNotification` function for my project
and now I'm stuck with `HINSTANCE hInstance;`

I want an coding example how to implement HINSTANCE in c++

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Wtsapi32.h"
#include <tchar.h>

#pragma comment( lib, "user32.lib" )

using namespace std;

static TCHAR szWindowClass[] = _T("win32app");
// The string that appears in the application's title bar.
static TCHAR szTitle[] = _T("Win32 Guided Tour Application");

void main()
{
    // Lock the workstation.
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(
        szWindowClass,
        szTitle,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        500, 100,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        GetModuleHandle(NULL),
        NULL
    );

    cout<< WTSRegisterSessionNotification(hWnd, NOTIFY_FOR_ALL_SESSIONS);;

    if (!LockWorkStation())
    {
        printf("LockWorkStation failed with %d\n", GetLastError());
    }

    cout << WTSRegisterSessionNotification(hWnd, NOTIFY_FOR_ALL_SESSIONS);;

    system("pause");
}
```

I want to implement `WTSRegisterSessionNotification(hwnd, NOTIFY_FOR_ALL_SESSIONS);`

I'm getting this error:

> LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _WTSRegisterSessionNotification@8 referenced in function _main

and find out what values it returns

Comment: There is no `HINSTANCE` involved with `WTSRegisterSessionNotification()`, so I don't know what you are trying to ask about that. But regarding the linker error, you simply need to link to `Wtsapi32.lib`, as the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsregistersessionnotification) says. Add a second `#pragma` for that. That being said, there is no need to call `WTSRegisterSessionNotification()` multiple times. And you need a message loop to receive the `WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE` messages that are sent to your registered `HWND`.

Comment: I want a specific function to work only when the system in in unlocked state. To do so I'm using WTSRegisterSessionNotification(). But the problem is I don't know how to implement it. secondly what other _#pragma_ I have to add?

Comment: `#pragma comment( lib, "wtsapi32.lib" )`

Comment: well the program is working now But  WTSRegisterSessionNotification() is returning same value before LockWorkStation and after Unlock

Comment: the *return value* is not what you need to look at. You need a message loop that listens for `WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE` messages. That will tell you when the user session is logged out and back in

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: Thank you .. Really grateful for your time  :)